# Сколько будет весить один символ в кодировке cp1251_general_ci?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица, в ней строки в кодировке `cp1251_general_ci`, сколько в байтах будет весить один символ?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251

Comment: `SELECT LENGTH(CONVERT('x' USING cp1251) COLLATE cp1251_general_ci);`

Answer (score 0):

Если вы в эту таблицу будете писать текст в формате Windows-1251, то на 1 символ придется 1 байт.

Если же у вас соединение с базой данных установлено utf8 (или utf8mb4) и писать в базу вы начнете текст в UTF-8, то на 1 символ будет приходится от 1 до 3 байт (или до 4 байт). И она их туда запишет.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ок, как мне проверить через что у меня соединение?